# How to avoid webpack bundle all files in one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

I'm using `webpack` with `serverless framework` and I would like to know if is possible avoid the bundling of all files.

This is my structure:

```
services/
|- checkups/
||
|| some_file.js
utils/
|- other_file.js
```

In `some_file`, I'm importing `other_file`:

```
// some_file.js
import otherFile from '../../utils/other_file/
```

And when I run the deploy, that runs webpack, all the files are turning in just one: `handle.js`, when I need them separate. Is that possible?

My current `webpack.config` is:

```
const path = require('path')
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals({ modulesDir: '../../node_modules' })],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      include: __dirname,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Webpack is a bundling application and is expected to condense all of your logic into smaller more downloadable files. You can generate multiple separate bundles if that is your intention?

Comment: Just because is expected, doesn't mind that should only work that way, no? My intention is to bundle all node_modules, but still respect the structure of my own files... :B